# How to set a comment on table using Laravel Schema Builder

Tags: laravel, comments, schema

How to set a comment on table using Laravel Schema Builder?

Column set:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('vendors', function (Blueprint $table) 
    {
        $table->comment('not working - error'); // not working - error
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('vendor', 255)->comment('Some comment.');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

But for the table?

Comment: Probably rejected because SQL Server has extended properties and other databases do not.

Answer (score 40):

Well I don't have a nice answer for you, but at least it works.

Here it is:

```
public function up()
{
    $tableName = 'vendors';

    Schema::create($tableName, function (Blueprint $table) 
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('vendor', 255)->comment('Some comment.');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `$tableName` comment 'My comment'");
}
```

Just add a DB statement after creating your table.

Comment: But how to put comments is specific to the driver. This answer shows how to do it if you're using MySQL. Using Postgres, you'd have to change the syntax to `DB::statement("COMMENT ON TABLE {$table_name} IS 'My comment'");` SQLite's comments cannot be set with a query like this and SqlServer is another matter entirely.

Comment: @IGP laravel doesn't provide an interface to set comments on tables, if you need to set comments for different drivers might be easier to just create your own table wrapper. Get the current db driver and based on that run the specific statement.

Comment: I did. Sort of. `switch ((new \ReflectionClass(Schema::getConnection()))->getShortName()) {}` This evaluates to either `'PostgresConnection'`, `'MySqlConnection'`, `'SQLiteConnection'` or `'SqlServerConnection'`, allowing me to make a different `DB::statement` depending on the driver.

Answer (score 3):

Before Laravel 9, only columns were allowed to comment. Since laravel 9 the ability to comment on the table itself has been added.See this [PR](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/42401) and the [Blog article](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-9-14-0)
If you would like to add a "comment" to a database table, you may invoke the comment method on the table instance. Table comments are currently only supported by **MySQL** and **Postgres**:

```
Schema::create('calculations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->comment('Business calculations');
 
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Great to see this feature!