# How to add comment to table (not column) in Laravel 5 migration?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

How to add comment to table (ot column) in Laravel 5 migration?

I currently know how to add comment to column like:

```
$table->tinyInteger('status')->comment('0: requested; -1: rejected; 1:confirmed');
```

But what about table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a comment on table using Laravel Schema Builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271843/how-to-set-a-comment-on-table-using-laravel-schema-builder)

Comment: Better and working answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34272884/1883256), like "num8er" commented.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Currently, Laravel does not allow (does not have functionality) to put comment on tables, so You have to use workaround in Your migration:

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `<YOUR_TABLE>` comment '<COMMENT>'");
```

Comment: you can make some static helper function e.g. setTableComment($table, $comment) which wrap above code  (to not use it directly in migration files, if some db not support above syntax)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Can you include an example of what such a function looks like and where it goes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For now there are no any option exist to add table comment like column add but then after you want to add the comment to table than you must have to use "DB" to add the comment to table.

For Example,

If you want to add the comment to website table then through below Syntax you can add the comment to table.

`DB::select("ALTER TABLE website COMMENT = 'This table contains the website information for the application'");`

**NOTE:** Before use above line you must have migrated website/ your table then n than you can use this.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `DB::statement()` and RAW SQL queries!

Just add the `comment()` chain method on `$table` variable:

```
$table->comment('your comment');
```

Comment: This was added in 9.x - so no Laravel 5.x support as requested by @mohsenJsh