# How to add comment in Mysql column using Laravel Migrations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

This is what I am trying to do

```
if (!Schema::hasColumn('account_settings', 'minimum_onsite_length')) {
        Schema::table('account_settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedInteger('minimum_onsite_length')
                ->default(180)
                ->nullable()
                ->comment('This is comments')
            ;
        });
    }
```

But comments are not showing in migration is there any thing I am missing here?

I have also looked to this question but it is not working [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493431/how-to-add-comment-to-table-not-column-in-laravel-5-migration)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add comment to table (not column) in Laravel 5 migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37493431/how-to-add-comment-to-table-not-column-in-laravel-5-migration)

Comment: @Jigs1212 I am adding to column not table see title

Comment: Are you sure that column doesn't exist already?
If it already exist then that code inside if block won't execute.

Comment: @AkshayKulkarni yess I am sure ..

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
if (!Schema::hasColumn('account_settings', 'minimum_onsite_length')) {
    Schema::table('account_settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('minimum_onsite_length')
            ->default(180)
            ->nullable()
            ->comment('This is comment');
    });
}
```

Ref Link [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-set-a-comment-on-table-column-using-schema-builder) and [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-modifiers).

Comment: According to official document of Laravel 5.7, comment can be added by "->comment('my comment')". https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations

Comment: Can confirm that, `->comment('my comment');` also works on Laravel 4.2.

Comment: I can confirm `->comment('my comment')` does work till date up to 7.x. More on official documentation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#column-modifiers

Comment: Note that this doesn't work when `->comment()` is chained after a `->references()` (since references returns a `ForeignKeyDefinition`)!